# Uploading files with Angular and nodejs multer

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I am trying to upload a file from angular 11 to nodejs multer, but I get undefined

[htlm file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLbht.jpg)
[the typesScrip code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N4fI.jpg)

My multer configuration
const multer = require('multer');

```
/**  */
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: (req, file, callback) => {
 callback(null, 'files');
 },
 filename: (req, file, callback) => {
 const name = file.originalname.split(' ').join('_');
 //const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];+ '.' + extension
 callback(null, name + Date.now() );
 }
});
 
module.exports = multer({storage: storage}).single('file');
```

this is my route code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


const upload = require('../middleware/multerConfig')

router.post('/test', upload, async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.file)
  }
);
```

and the result of console

```
MongoDB Connected
::ffff:192.168.23.101 - - [03/Nov/2021:14:41:01 +0000] "OPTIONS /api/test HTTP/1.1" 200 8
{ file: {} }
undefined
(node:13444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'file' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach and according to doc of multer, you have to add this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


const upload = require('../middleware/multerConfig')

function fileUpload(req, res, next) {
    upload.single('file')(req, res, next);
}

router.post('/test', fileUpload, async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.file)
  }
);
```

I hope it is resolved

Comment: merci pour la réponse mais , toujours pas

Comment: Je vous en prie:)